# Convert Bigint to Date in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, bigint

I have a BigINT column with value for example: `20140130`. This needs to be converted to a date column `2014/01/30`, so in format `yyyy/MM/dd` using PostgreSQL.

Please, how can this be done ?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the value to a string and then use the `to_date()` function:

```
select to_date(20140130::text, 'yyyymmdd');
```

More details about the to_date() function in the manual:
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

More information about casting values in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

> *converted to a date column ... format yyyy/MM/dd*

A `date` column does ***not*** have "a format". Any format you see being applied to a `date` (or `timestamp`) column is done by the client application (e.g. `psql` or any other SQL client).

The result of the `to_date()` function is  a `date` which can be formatted to any display you like using the to_char()` function.

```
select to_char(to_date(20140130::text, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd.mm.yyyy');
select to_char(to_date(20140130::text, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

But formatting dates is better left to the frontend and should not be done in SQL.

You should also *seriously* consider to fix your table design and use a proper `date` date column rather than an "encoded" bigint value.

Comment: +1 for suggesting "You should also seriously consider to fix your table design".